What is the definition of "multiple component of germ"?
Recently I read a paper and I am confused with a word "multiple components", but I don't find its definition in this paper. I guess it is about the singularity. Here is a picture.

You can find the paper by this link.
Another picture is

I want a rigorous definition. And how to determine if a given function has multiple components? (An example is $x^2 y^2$)

I think they meant multiple component of germ, not of analytic functions?

@Divide1918 I think you are right. But what is the component of germ?

What is the text referred to in the second picture as [8]? They might define it more explicitly there.

@Divide1918  It is the above link, see also the new picture.
